# Make a Passive Rigid Body Disappear

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have a scene where balls are falling inside an invisible passive cylinder and after a moment I would like a larger ball for each color to squash them but I do not want to employ cell fractures because my cylinder is invisible so, is there a way to keyframe my ball containers and make them totally disappear so that my balls will explode all over the place?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the answer to my problem. It seems you can keyframe a rigid body's collision group and so I did. by pressing I on the collision group layer and positioning your marker to the specific keyframe where you want your rigid body to not affect other meshes.